# ListRemoveDuplicates result has a comma at the end

Tags: list, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, lucee

When using `listRemoveDuplicates` in Lucee, it removes the duplicate values but still leaves the delimiter in end of the value.

Ex:

```
<cfset myUsers = 'sathish,sathish'>
<cfset removeDups = listRemoveDuplicates(myUsers)>

<cfdump var="#removeDups#" />
```

This produces the output:

```
sathish,
```

However, when checking this same function with Adobe ColdFusion, it produces the correct value (no comma at the end):

```
sathish
```

How can I omit the comma delimiter in Lucee?

Comment: Looks like there has already been a bug entered for this - https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-736

Comment: Thanks Miguel-F, But i got the function ListCompact() is solve my problem. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surfing the Lucee documentation, I found the [ListCompact()](http://docs.lucee.org/reference/functions/listcompact.html) function which returns the correct value.

```
<cfset myUsers = 'sathish,sathish'>
<cfset removeDups = listCompact(listRemoveDuplicates(myUsers))>
<cfdump var="#removeDups#" />
```

Comment: This function works on lucee server only. Not adobe coldfusion.. :-(

Comment: Another workaround is to convert it to an array and back again: `arrayToList(listToArray(removeDups))`. Much klunkier than `ListCompact`, but it is compatible with both engines if that is a concern.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a custom function like this:

```
<cffunction name="UDF_listRemoveDuplicates" access="public">
    <cfargument name="list" type="string" required="yes">

    <!--- Hash Map to maintain the order --->
    <cfset local.hashMap = createObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init()>

    <!--- Add list values as key to Hash Map --->
    <cfloop list="#arguments.list#" index="local.value" delimiters=",">
        <cfset local.hashMap[local.value] = 1>
    </cfloop>

    <!--- Return list of Keys --->
    <cfreturn structKeyList(local.hashMap, ",")>
</cffunction>

<cfoutput>#UDF_listRemoveDuplicates("sathish,sathish")#</cfoutput>
```

This should work on both. (Not tested on Lucee)

Comment: Thx for your answer @Beginner. Its already working fine in Adove Coldfusion server. But I am facing issue only with Lucee server. We don't to create like this custom function for this issue. That issue also fixed with that function listCompact().

Comment: Great! Your answer is working on lucee. Thanks a lot.. :-)

Comment: Beginner One doubt, here why we need to createObject for linkedHashMap?? Shall we create a struct variable to store the looping data??

Comment: @SathishK - It is used because a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) maintains the order of the original list items. A regular structure does not.

Comment: @Beginner - One important difference is that unlike CF structures, LinkedHashMap's are case sensitive.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for the info.  :)

Comment: You are welcome guys. (Love the java stuff, but always have to remind myself of the little differences so they do not come back to bite me ;-)